# php is throwing a fatal error about the sql functions i am using in my php

Tags: php, sql

this is a web service php page interacting with an android app, using the  sql select statement to pull data from a database.

this pulls a total number of orders, and total price of those over the past 7 days. im having problems with php using the count sql function

```
$STH = $conn->prepare('SELECT count(orderid) as totalorders, sum(totalprice) as totalprice from orders where orderDate BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)  AND CURDATE()');
$STH->execute();
$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//json array to pass data to an android app
$arr = array("status" => "Okay" ,
"totalOrders" => "totalordersvar", 
"totalPrice" => "totalpricevar");
echo "json array created";
```

this seems to be the new source of the problems while i am trying to bind the selected data to pass to json

```
    $results = $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $totalOrders = $STH->fetch('count(orderid)');
    $totalPrice = $STH->fetch('sum(totalprice)');
```

errors it is currently throwning

reguarding both variables

PDOStatement::fetch() expects parameter 1 to be integer, string given

Comment: You say it is *throwing a fatal error*, can you show what the error is, it helps understand the problem.

Comment: It's always easier to see what a problem is when you include any relevant messages you are getting.  Usually the message has useful information which will help.

Comment: it would really help us if we won't have to guess the error and you show us what error it's throwing

Comment: sorry, i have them in there now, i am using web hosting so it takes a minute to force a new error log through

Comment: You need to put the names of the columns in quotes as they are strings and not functions(or values) - `$STH->fetch('count(orderid)');`

Comment: I suggest you consult the documentation for [`fetch()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php). If you're going to pass any arguments, the first one should be `int $fetch_style`, not the column that you want. Try `$result = $STH->fetch(); $totalOrders = $result['totalorders']; $totalPrice = $results['totalprice'];`

Comment: i changed the second results to result and it now works! thank you for bearing with me, ive been working for 23 hours. you da best